# jQuery .scrollTop not scrolling properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've got the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(window.location.hash) {
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
    }, 1000);

  }
})
```

Which I've built with the help of code taken from StackOverflow.
I call the page at `url#destination` so actually it should scroll to the element whose ID is the page Hash. The element exists and the page scrolls down, but not to the exact element offset, but a bit more above. It could be just fine but I want it to work as I expected. 
So I now show you the console results:

```
>>>$("body").scrollTop()
>1155

>>>$("#aboutus").offset().top
>1672.890625
```

Could someone explain this to me? Because I cannot understand anything here.

Comment: It works for me well. Try to create a blank page, where is nothing, just jquery, and 3 divs, first and third with a big height, and try to scrollTo to the 2nd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm... It works fine for me. Maybe the problem is, as a user pointed in the comments, the elements haven't loaded yet so you should use `$(window).load()`. But if you use that, your code won't work fine since the browsers have the built-in method that when a hash exists in the url, it goes directly wherever the element whose id is the hash is. This happens because this action is triggered before the .load event detection in your javascript code. So, if you want to make sure the code works, replace the targeting of the element with other attribute like:

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
  if(window.location.hash) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: $('*[idt="'+(window.location.hash).replace("#", "")+'"]').offset().top
      }, 1000);
    }, 130)


  }
})
```

This should make fully sure the animation works properly, since there's no element that has got such a hash, and the js code manages the same way.

Comment: Nevertheless, I am pretty sure there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't scroll to the very bottom is because your last element hasn't been added to the DOM at the time of `scrollTop` execution.

Make `scrollTop` asynchronous to wait until the DOM has completely rendered:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
}, 0);
```

Comment: I could've spent hours trying to figure that out. Thanks mate